# Check pressed mouse button when page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check in my javascript code which mouse buttons are pressed. It's not so hard to do but I need to check it when a page is just loading and no mousedown event was fired in that page yet. For example when onload event is fired. Is it possible? It can be done with jQuery too if it wouldn't be done only with javascript.

Comment: If something is not possible with JavaScript, it won't be possible with jQuery either, as *it is* JavaScript...

Comment: You could add a few event listeners like `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `mousemove` to the `window`. You can then read the button states on the `DOMContentLoaded` event. As far as I know there’s no way to detect mouse button state changes _before_ a page begins loading… With `mousedown` you can look at the `buttons` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not provide mouse button state query outside of event handlers.

But in principle you can check if body is in :active state thus has mouse pressed on it.

```
console.log($(document.body).is(":active"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you need to get clicks before the page finishes loading (and after) you could do it using load instead of ready.

```
$(document).load(onLoad);

function(onLoad){
  $('body').mousedown(function(event){
    var mouseClick = [];
    mouseClick.push(event.which);
  });
}
```

or whatever mouse click tracking code you need.